# foreign source code pre-processing with Clojure

Tags: clojure, templating

I'd like to preprocess code from another language like so:

```
Predicate1(X) => Predicate2(Y)
<% (clojure-func "Predicate3" "X" "Y") %>
```

Basically, what's inside angle brackets gets executed and the emitted string output inserted into the string. I see that there are HTML templating libraries. I'm wondering if I can get by with something like Clojure macros. It is possible that I'm not aware of the benefits provided by a templating library like [Fleet](https://github.com/Flamefork/fleet) or [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer), and need some guidance.

In the above example I want to create combinations of more expressions:

```
Predicate3(X_a) => Predicate2(Y)
Predicate3(X_b) => Predicate2(Y)
```

Ultimately, I do need to keep track of variables of the foreign language. For this purpose pre-processing may be the wrong approach and that instead I'm better off doing complete code-generation.

P.S.: For those of you wondering I'm trying to extend the language of Markov Logic Networks (MLN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure macros will not help you directly with this. Macros still require expressions to be in essentially Clojure readable syntax with invocations of the form `(macro arg1 arg...)`.

Other Lisps do allow you to extend the readable syntax with reader macros, but Clojure made a decision not to allow them.

Comment: Clojure world is small. I was on your blog the other day :)